# Apache Camel set httpClientConfigurer

Tags: spring-boot, http, apache-camel

I am using apache camel + spring boot is there a way to set the httpClientConfigurer other than passing in the url of camel route "host-path+"?httpClientConfigurer=#config""

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it globally, for **ALL** http calls made by your http component (inside your CamelContext)

```
HttpComponent httpComponent = context.getComponent("http", HttpComponent.class);
httpComponent.setHttpClientConfigurer(new MyCustomConfigurer() );
```